# Average monthly_orders grouped by country and device

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compute

- the **average_monthly_orders** grouped by **device** and **country**
- **average_monthly_orders** is based on daily **count_orders** which is averaged over a given month

Main table

```
date        country  device  count_orders
2019-01-01  UK       phone    100
2019-01-02  UK       tablet   200
2019-01-03  UK       phone    200
2019-01-04  UK       phone    300
2019-01-05  UK       tablet   400
2019-01-06  UK       phone    400

2019-01-01  JP       phone    200
2019-01-02  JP       tablet   100
2019-01-03  JP       phone    100
2019-01-04  JP       phone    500
2019-01-05  JP       tablet   300
2019-01-06  JP       phone    300
```

Output table

```
month       country  device  average_monthly_orders
January-19  UK       phone   32 
January-19  UK       tablet  19 
January-19  JP       phone   35
January-19  JP       tabet   13
```

Comment: How is the average for a month 32?

Answer (score 1):

Use, [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the `date` column into pandas datetime series, then use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the dataframe on `month`, `country` and `device`, now aggregate the `count_orders` in grouped dataframe using `sum`. Now use [`Series.floordiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.floordiv.html) to divide the `average_monthly_orders` column in the new dataframe by the corresponding days in the month which can be obtained using [`Series.dt.daysinmonth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.daysinmonth.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df1 = (
    df.groupby([df['date'].dt.strftime('%B-%y'), 'country', 'device'], sort=False)
    .agg(average_monthly_orders=('count_orders', 'sum'))
    .reset_index()
)

df1['average_monthly_orders'] = (
    df1['average_monthly_orders'].floordiv(pd.to_datetime(
        df1['date'], format='%B-%y').dt.daysinmonth)
)
```

---

```
# print(df1)
         date country  device  average_monthly_orders
0  January-19      UK   phone                      32
1  January-19      UK  tablet                      19
2  January-19      JP   phone                      35
3  January-19      JP  tablet                      12
```

Comment: @user12625679 Does this anwered your question?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael its always nice to hear from you :).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you've provided:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%B-%y')
df = df.groupby(by=['month', 'country', 'device'], as_index=False).mean().rename(columns={'count_orders': 'average_monthly_orders'})
print(df)

        month country  device  count_orders
0  January-19      JP   phone           275
1  January-19      JP  tablet           200
2  January-19      UK   phone           250
3  January-19      UK  tablet           300
```

Comment: Yes, of course :) just thought this might be easier to read

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average monthly orders to be stored in the output table, you will need to create four separate average monthly order variables, one for each group. Then, iterate through all the data, and only contributing to the value of a given monthly average based on information in the other columns of the main table.